# Where is eta in statsmodels GLM?

Tags: python, statsmodels, glm

Where is the linear predictors (eta) located in the statsmodels.GLM class?

If a fitted model `mdl = sm.GLM(Y, X, family = family()).fit()` is equal to R's `mdl <- glm.fit(X, Y, family = family())`, then R's eta can be found `mdl$linear.predictors`. But i can't seem to find eta in statsmodels.

Right now i calculate them by `X @ mdl.params`, which seems a bit tedious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eta` is not a very descriptive name. The internal name in statsmodels is `linpred`.

The linear predictor including offset and exposure can be obtained using the results predict method

`results_glm.predict(..., linear=True)`

or `md1.predict` in your case.

Offset can be set to zero using the keyword to obtain the linear predictor without offset, similar for exposure.